# Replace numbers with letters - powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, for-loop, replace

I have an array element that I am trying to replace all the numbers with letters. This is the array element before manipulation:

```
$a[0].object

--- OUTPUT ---
518773112
```

I convert the number to a string and store it in `$e`. Then I find the length of that string and store that in `$d`

```
$e = $a[0].object.ToString()
$d = $a[0].object.ToString().length
$e
$d

---OUTPUT---
518773112
9
```

Then I try to looping through the string to replace the numbers with letters. I place `$i` in the Substring to get the number that I'm trying to replace. Then I use an `if-statement` to see if that substring is equal to a number, and if so, then I use the replace method to try and replace the number with a letter.

```
for($i=0; $i -lt $d; $i++){
    $pos = $e.Substring($i,1)
    if($pos -eq '0'){$e += $pos.replace('0', 'A')}
    if($pos -eq '1'){$e += $pos.replace('1', 'B')}
    if($pos -eq '2'){$e += $pos.replace('2', 'C')}
    if($pos -eq '3'){$e += $pos.replace('3', 'D')}
    if($pos -eq '4'){$e += $pos.replace('4', 'E')}
    if($pos -eq '5'){$e += $pos.replace('5', 'F')}
    if($pos -eq '6'){$e += $pos.replace('6', 'G')}
    if($pos -eq '7'){$e += $pos.replace('7', 'H')}
    if($pos -eq '8'){$e += $pos.replace('8', 'I')}
    if($pos -eq '9'){$e += $pos.replace('9', 'J')}
}
```

My issue though, is it will concatenate the letters to the end of the number string:

```
518773112FBIHHDBBC
```

Likely, because I have `+=` in my `then` portion of my `if-statement`. However, when I replace `+=` with `=` I get an error with my Substring method saying:

```
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
```

I've checked `$i` and `$d` and they are set correctly before I run the loop. So, I'm a little confused. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add a concise alternative to the existing, helpful answers, via a single, regex-based 
[`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation:

```sh
# PowerShell (Core) 7+ only.
# -> 'FBIHHDBBC'
'518773112' -replace '\d', {  [char] ([int] [char] 'A' + [int] $_.Value) }

# Windows PowerShell alternative:
# (requires direct use of underlying .NET APIs)
[regex]::Replace('518773112', '\d', { param($m) [char] ([int] [char] 'A' + [int] $m.Value) })
```

- Regex escape sequence `\d` matches any single decimal digit.
- `[int] [char] 'A' + [int] $_.Value` adds the value of the captured digit (`$_.Value`) as an integer to the integer representation of character `A`, i.e. it adds an offset to the *Unicode code point* of `A`.
- The resulting code point is then re-converted to a character (`[char]`), which yields the letter of interest.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Leaving the inefficiency of your approach aside, the problem was that you tried to build your *result* string in the same variable as the *input* string:

- `+=` therefore *appended* the desired result to the input string
- Just `=` essentially *replaced* the input string with the single character being processed, causing subsequent `.Substring()` calls to fail, given that the string was now reduced to a single character.

The *immediate* fix would have been to build the result in a *new variable* (but note that all the solutions presented in the answers here a preferable):

```sh
$e = '518773112'
$d = $e.Length

$result = '' # initialize result string
for($i=0; $i -lt $d; $i++){
  $pos = $e.Substring($i,1)
  # Use += on *$result*
  if($pos -eq '0'){$result += $pos.replace('0', 'A')}
  if($pos -eq '1'){$result += $pos.replace('1', 'B')}
  if($pos -eq '2'){$result += $pos.replace('2', 'C')}
  if($pos -eq '3'){$result += $pos.replace('3', 'D')}
  if($pos -eq '4'){$result += $pos.replace('4', 'E')}
  if($pos -eq '5'){$result += $pos.replace('5', 'F')}
  if($pos -eq '6'){$result += $pos.replace('6', 'G')}
  if($pos -eq '7'){$result += $pos.replace('7', 'H')}
  if($pos -eq '8'){$result += $pos.replace('8', 'I')}
  if($pos -eq '9'){$result += $pos.replace('9', 'J')}
}

$result # Output the result: -> 'FBIHHDBBC'
```

Answer (score 5):

The `String.Replace()` method will replace *any* matching character or substring for you, you don't need to handle (or even care about) each position in the string separately:

```
$e = '518773112'

foreach($digit in 0..9){
  # calculate next letter character
  $substitute = ($digit + 'A'[0]) -as [char]

  # replace all instances of $digit with $substitute
  $e = $e.Replace("$digit", $substitute)
}
```

The value of `$e` is now "FBIHHDBBC"

Comment: Really like this method! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Here's my two cents:

```
-join ('518773112' -split '(.)' -ne '' | Foreach-Object { [char]([int]$_ + 65)})
```

Result:

```
FBIHHDBBC
```

Alternative with `Select-Object`:

```
-join ('518773112' -split '(.)' -ne '' | Select-Object @{Name = 'Chr'; Expression = {[char]([int]$_ + 65)}}).Chr
```

Comment: `-split '(?<=\G.)(?!$)'` if you want to avoid `-ne ''` :-D

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Wow... Heavy Regex ;)

Comment: Super great answer. Like this alternative method!

Answer (score 4):

Another concise one (inspired by [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71956458/7571258)):

```
-join '518773112'.ToCharArray().ForEach{[char]([int]$_ + 17)}
```

This [converts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=net-6.0#system-string-tochararray) the input string into a char array, then loops over each character using PowerShell's intrinsic method [`ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#foreachscriptblock-expression).

In the script block of `ForEach` the code point of the character is incremented to be in the range of numeric digits `'0'`..`'9'`, then converted back into a character. The "magic" number `17` is just the difference between the code points of characters `'A'` and `'0'` (i. e. `[int][char]'A' - [int][char]'0'` outputs `17`).

Finally the unary form of the [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.2) operator is used to create a single string from the individual characters.

Answer (score 3):

**Note, this example assumes the values are only integers.**

Here is one way how you can approach this, first generate a charset from `A` to `J` then split the value of the `.object` property to generate an array of these numbers which then we can use for [indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#index-operator--) on the charset:

```sh
$char = [char[]]([char]'A'..[char]'J')
$a = [pscustomobject]@{
    object = 518773112
}
$transform = $a.object.ToString() -split '' -ne ''
$a.object = [string]::new($char[$transform])
```

The result should be:

```
PS /> $a

object
------
FBIHHDBBC
```

Answer (score 3):

`$e` will showed like concatenated , it's because you connect the `$e` through the loop.

The function `subString` return a copy of `$e` that subed.

you should declare a new varibel ,

```
$a[0] = 518773112;
$e = $a[0].ToString()
$d = $a[0].ToString().length

$str = ""
for($i=0; $i -lt $d; $i++){
    $pos = $e.Substring($i,1)
    if($pos -eq '0'){$str += $pos.replace('0', 'A')}
    if($pos -eq '1'){$str += $pos.replace('1', 'B')}
    if($pos -eq '2'){$str += $pos.replace('2', 'C')}
    if($pos -eq '3'){$str += $pos.replace('3', 'D')}
    if($pos -eq '4'){$str += $pos.replace('4', 'E')}
    if($pos -eq '5'){$str += $pos.replace('5', 'F')}
    if($pos -eq '6'){$str += $pos.replace('6', 'G')}
    if($pos -eq '7'){$str += $pos.replace('7', 'H')}
    if($pos -eq '8'){$str += $pos.replace('8', 'I')}
    if($pos -eq '9'){$str += $pos.replace('9', 'J')}
}

Write-Output $str;
```

although there are better ways to do the same job